# Equality of real numbers : transitivity holds or not with this definition ??

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I was reading this book called "The Taylor series" by Paul Dienes.
He wrote and I quote,
"We say that the positive real number
$a=a_0.a_1a_2a_3a_4... $ Precedes $b=b_0.b_1b_2b_3.. $ if 
$a_0<b_0$ 
or $a_0=b_0 ,a_1=b_1, a_2=b_2....                      a_{n-1} =b_{n-1}$ 
But $a_n<b_n$ .
We say that b is between a and c if either a precedes b and b precedes c OR  c precedes b and b precedes a.
Definition of equality :- a=b if there is no number between a and b. "
Now my question is what happens to transitivity of equality in this case?
If there is no number between a and b a=b .
If there is no number between b and c  ,b=c.
And transitivity now implies a=c , but how can it be since b lies between a and c??
 Also, suppose a=1.9999.... and b =2 , then we know a

Comment: Where did you get that $b$ is between $a$ and $c$ from?

Comment: @Arthur Also, suppose a=1.9999.... and b =2 , then we know a <b . So a definitely precedes b.  And by the definition of equality a=b. Can these 2 hold together??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convince yourself that the only way how string $a$ can precede string $b$ with no string in between is when
$$a=a_0.a_1a_2\ldots a_{r-1} a_r99999\ldots,\qquad b=a_0.a_1a_2\ldots a_{r-1} b_r00000\ldots\ ,$$
whereby $0\leq a_r<9$ and $b_r=a_r+1$. It then follows that the situation you are afraid of cannot occur.